# How to switch AWS CLI to Python 3.7 on macOS?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

On macOS Mojave 10.14.6, have the following versions of python installed:

Python 2.7.16

```
Python 2.7.16 (default, May 17 2019, 18:32:33) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Python 3

```
Python 3.7.4 (v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 14:54:52) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Installed AWS CLI using these steps:

```
curl "https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip" -o "awscli-bundle.zip"
unzip awscli-bundle.zip
sudo ./awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws
```

Now, when I test aws from the command line using `aws --version`

```
aws-cli/1.16.247 Python/2.7.16 Darwin/18.7.0 botocore/1.12.237
```

Question(s):

Is this correct?

Is it supposed to be using Python 3.7.4 instead?

If so, how can I switch this over?

Answer (score 1):

By default the installer will use whatever is in your path for `python`.

If you want to use Python 3, you need to run something like this to run the installer:

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/python3 awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws
```

Replace `/usr/local/bin/python3` with your path for Python 3 if it's different.

All of this said, if you have both Python environments installed, I'm not aware of any reason to prefer one version over the other for the AWS CLI tool.

Comment: Thanks - just wondering if AWS CLI is more optimized or meant to use with`python3`.